# com.android.mms crashes with ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE action in intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mms

I am trying to send multiple images with com.android.mms via intents, but it crashes.

The mms works correctly when I send a single image using ACTION_SEND.

Does any one have some insights as to why this is the case? ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE should be a valid action for mms because the mms app is displayed in the chooser dialog (Messages icons in the image below).

I use the following codes to open a chooser dialog.

```
public static void openDialog(Context context,
                              String title,
                              String snippet,
                              Set<String> fileUrls) {

    if (fileUrls != null && !fileUrls.isEmpty()) {

        String shareText =
                prepareShareText(context, snippet);

        ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        for (String path : fileUrls) {
            File file = new File(path); 
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
                    file);
            files.add(uri);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title); 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText); 

        intent.setType("image/*"); 
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files); 
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share media"));
    }
}
```

[image]

When I select "Messages" (com.android.mms), the mms app tries to open but crashes with the following errors

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15195)
                     at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2492)
                     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
                     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080a7f (t=7 e=2687) in package 0 (error -75)
W/Settings: Setting window_animation_scale has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
E/Qdio::ParseQdio: File Open Error
E/Qdio::ParseQdio: File Open Error

E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 0 columns.
W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e93da0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: addAttachment
                  Process: com.android.mms, PID: 13192
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                      at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                      at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:439)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                      at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
                      at com.android.mms.ui.MessageUtils.getMimeTypeFromUri(MessageUtils.java:6323)
                      at com.android.mms.util.HandleComposerAttachment$32.run(HandleComposerAttachment.java:2476)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageMms
```

**Edit:**

Do note that the error log is from the com.android.mms app itself (not from my app). I selected "no filters" on the logcat to see them.

the permission denial error also appears when I send a single image, but it does not cause a "FATAL EXCEPTION: addAttachment" crash.

Comment: Your errors state `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`. Did you declare this in the manifest? If you haven't and it is not required, you should investigate why this error appears.

Comment: @IshitaSinha, that error is from com.android.mms app after select "no filters" on my logcat. It does not originate from my app. Edit: the permission error also appears when I send a single image in MMS (so it don't seem to be causing the crash). Sending a single image works correctly.

Comment: Try removing `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);` when sending multiple.

Comment: @MikeM. removing EXTRA_TEXT does not help. mms app still crashes.